# HTML2PDF footer issue on auto breaked page

Tags: php, html2pdf

I am generating PDF using HTML2PDF, it's working fine. But as my data is dynamic so footer is coming only in last page if OUTPUT PDF is more than 1 page. I am using below code:

```
<page backtop="0" backbottom="30mm">
    <page_header>
           // Header contnet here
    </page_header>         
    // Dynamic body content here
    <page_footer>
             // Footer contnet here
    </page_footer>
```

As header is coming in each page but same is not working for footer.

I found a property `footer="page"` which gives me page no in each page but as my Footer content is a different html so i need that to print in each page.

Comment: please add here full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this url:
https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/issues/297

You need to add page footer tag before body content:

```
<page backtop="0" backbottom="30mm">
    <page_header>
       // Header contnet here
    </page_header>         
    <page_footer>
       // Footer contnet here
    </page_footer>
    // Dynamic body content here
<page>
```